# C socket read() return value

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I'm working on a C project to send a file from one IP address to another, using a server/client structure. From reading other posts, I understand that reading from a socket will return 0 only if the socket is closed.

Relevant code on server side (socket(), bind(), and accept() behave as expected)

```
char *toSend = malloc(packet_size);
size_t bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = fread(toSend, sizeof(char), packet_size, fp)) > 0) {
printf("Sending: %s \n", toSend);
    write(newsockfd, toSend);
    usleep(packet_delay*1000000);
}
```

On client side:

```
char buffer[256];
int numRead;
while ((numRead = read(sockfd, buffer, 255)) > 0) {                        
  printf("read %d\n", numRead);                                                       
  printf("%s\n", buffer);
  fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 255, fp);                                                                     
}
```

The client connect() call returns 0 for success, but the first call to read(sockfd, buffer, 255) returns 0, despite the socket being open at the time; this seems like it shouldn't be possible. Does anyone have some tips? Thank you.

Comment: You must check `toSend == NULL` right after `malloc()` if you want to prevent some wierd things to happen.

Comment: what does this `write(newsockfd, toSend);` mean? you have to specify the length.

Comment: On the server side, change `write(newsockfd, toSend)` to `write(newsockfd, toSend, bytesRead)`, or `send(newsockfd, toSend, bytesRead, 0)`.  On the client side, change `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 255, fp)` to `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), numRead, fp)`.

Comment: Also, on the server side, change `printf("Sending: %s \n", toSend)` to `printf("Sending: %.*s \n", bytesRead, toSend)`, and on the client side change `printf("%s\n", buffer)` to `printf("%.*s\n", numRead, buffer)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are writing the data in the wrong way, do you have a wrapper for the [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) system call?

The correct signature is

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

so you must pass the length of the data you are writing, also check if it succeded writing by capturing the return value and checking it properly.

The return value of `0` from `read()` doesn't mean an error happened, it means that there was no data to read, when there is an error `read()` returns `-1`.

If you need to wait until there is data, use [`select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) this is an example

```
fd_set         set;
struct timeval tv;

FD_ZERO(&set);
FD_SET(sockfd, &set);

tv.tv_sec  = TIMEOUT;
tv.tv_usec = 0;

if ((select(sockfd + 1, NULL, &set, NULL, &tv) != 1) || (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &set) == 0))
    return timedOutWaitingForData();

proceedReadingFrom(sockfd);
```

as you see, you are free to set the timeout value.

Comment: Hi iharob, thanks for the help. Checked toSend and its contents; the pointer is not null and the contents are as expected. About using the select() call: I think my issue isn't waiting for data, it's that I never get any data. I tried changing the while loop in client to a while(1) and never got a nonzero numRead. What are some reasons this may happen, even though both sides accepted the connection?

Comment: Zero doesn't mean there was no data to read. It means you reached end of stream. In the case of a socket, it means the peer closed the connection. SO_RCVTIMEO is considerably simpler than this, if supported on your platform.